Django makemessages, TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
I'm trying to create a multi language Django project in pycharm. But have struggled for the whole day figuring out why the makemessages doesn't generate .po files. So I reach out for some help.
settings.py
from pathlib import Path
import os
from decouple import config
from unipath import Path
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
import environ

env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()


BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
CORE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale/'),
)
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
]

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_ROOT = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')]


When I run python manage.py makemessages -l fr I get the following response:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py", line 52, in <module>
    run_command()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py", line 46, in run_command
    run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 225, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/famronnebratt/PycharmProjects/CompValid3/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/famronnebratt/PycharmProjects/CompValid3/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/famronnebratt/PycharmProjects/CompValid3/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/famronnebratt/PycharmProjects/CompValid3/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/famronnebratt/PycharmProjects/CompValid3/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/famronnebratt/PycharmProjects/CompValid3/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/famronnebratt/PycharmProjects/CompValid3/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 430, in handle
    potfiles = self.build_potfiles()
  File "/Users/famronnebratt/PycharmProjects/CompValid3/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 506, in build_potfiles
    file_list = self.find_files(".")
  File "/Users/famronnebratt/PycharmProjects/CompValid3/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 543, in find_files
    ignored_roots = [
  File "/Users/famronnebratt/PycharmProjects/CompValid3/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 544, in <listcomp>
    os.path.normpath(p)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/posixpath.py", line 336, in normpath
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Process finished with exit code 1


Share the MEDIA_ROOT and STATIC_ROOT.

Thanks to the comments by willeM and Sunderam I found the problem.
The django-import-export package uses the xlwt package. There is a fix for this.
https://gist.github.com/federicobond/fd59c7b22b90795e26d2
I found it easier to manually replace all
# -*- coding: windows-1252 -*-

with
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

in the .py files in the xlwt folder

I'm Happy, you found the solution ;)

The cause is not the LOCALE_PATHS. Django ignores the STATIC_ROOT [Django-doc] and MEDIA_ROOT [Django-doc]. Indeed:

def find_files(self, root):
    """
    Get all files in the given root. Also check that there is a matching
    locale dir for each file.
    """
    all_files = []
    ignored_roots = []
    if self.settings_available:
        ignored_roots = [
            os.path.normpath(p)
            for p in (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, settings.STATIC_ROOT)
            if p
        ]
    # …

These are apparently (non-empty) lists in your settings.py.
You thus should rewrite these settings, so:
# settings.py

# …

STATIC_ROOT = [my_path1]
MEDIA_ROOT = [my_path2]
should be rewritten to:
# settings.py

# …

STATIC_ROOT = my_path1
MEDIA_ROOT = my_path2
and the same with MEDIA_ROOT.

If I understand you correctly I should set MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'). But then I get a Non-ASCII string error. Reference: https://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html. But perhaps I missunderstand you?

@jonas To resolve this, you need to ensure that your Python files are properly encoded. According to PEP 263, you can specify the encoding of your Python source files by including a special comment at the top of each file.
For example, to specify UTF-8 encoding, you can add this line at the top of your settings.py file: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-. After adding this line, try running the makemessages command again to see if the error persists.

@Jonas: likely you used some non-ASCII character, and you did not specify the encoding.
